# C# IQueryable .Union reset sorting

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have the following code:

```
var expressions = new List<IQueryable<Container>>();

var containers1 = containers
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.ContainerReference1, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")
             || EF.Functions.Like(x.ContainerReference2, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"))
    .OrderBy(x => x.ContainerReference1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.ContainerReference2)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated);
expressions.Add(containers1);

var containers2 = containers
                  .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Description, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"))
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Description)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated);
expressions.Add(containers2);

var containers3 = containers.Where(x => x.ContactEmails
                            .OrderBy(y => y.Email)
                            .ThenBy(y => y.DisplayName)
                            .Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(y.Email, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")
                                 || EF.Functions.Like(y.DisplayName, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")))
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated);
expressions.Add(containers3);

var containers4 = containers
                            .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Keywords, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"))
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Keywords)
                            .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated);
expressions.Add(containers4);

containers = expressions.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc.Union(i));
```

But after `.Union` operation sorting is reset.
How can I prevent resetting of sorting?

Comment: Union is a set operation. It'll eliminate duplicates. So in what way should sorting be preserved if the same container would e.g. be the first from `containers1` and the third from `containers4` - it can't be in two places at the same time. That's the general problem, you really need to preserve enough information past the point of merging results such that you can sort afterwards.

Comment: How can I resolve that? Use `.Concat` instead `.Union`?

Comment: If all you want is to add one collection after the other, yes, `Concat` is how you do that. `Union` is not the same thing.

Comment: I want to save sorting and unique result set. Maybe `Distinct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Union` operator does not preserve the order of the elements. You need to dynamically construct the sorting logic based on the presence of data

```
var expressions = new List<IQueryable<Container>>();
var sortingExpressions = new List<Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>>();

var containers1 = containers
        .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.ContainerReference1, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(x.ContainerReference2, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"));
if (containers1.Any())
{
    var containers1Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(x => x
        .OrderBy(y => y.ContainerReference1)
        .ThenBy(y => y.ContainerReference2)
        .ThenByDescending(y => y.DateUpdated));

    expressions.Add(containers1);
    sortingExpressions.Add(containers1Sorting);
}

var containers2 = containers
          .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Description, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"));
if (containers2.Any())
{
    var containers2Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(x => x
        .OrderBy(y => y.Description)
        .ThenByDescending(y => y.DateUpdated));

    expressions.Add(containers2);
    sortingExpressions.Add(containers2Sorting);
}

var containers3 = containers
        .Where(x => x.ContactEmails
            .Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(y.Email, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")
                || EF.Functions.Like(y.DisplayName, $"%{message.SearchValue}%")));
if (containers3.Any())
{
    var containers3Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(x => x
        .OrderBy(y => y.ContactEmails.OrderBy(z => z.Email).ThenBy(z => z.DisplayName))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated));

    expressions.Add(containers3);
    sortingExpressions.Add(containers3Sorting);
}

var containers4 = containers
      .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Keywords, $"%{message.SearchValue}%"));
if (containers4.Any())
{
    var containers4Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(x => x
        .OrderBy(y => y.Keywords)
        .ThenByDescending(y => y.DateUpdated));

    expressions.Add(containers4);
    sortingExpressions.Add(containers4Sorting);
}

var mergedContainers = expressions.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc.Union(i));

if (sortingExpressions.Any())
{
    var mergedSorting = sortingExpressions
        .Aggregate((acc, next) => q => next(acc(q)));

    containers = mergedSorting(mergedContainers);
}
else
{
    containers = mergedContainers.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated);
}
```

Comment: what about other ordering `Description`, `ContactEmails` etc? And what if `containers1` is empty and I don't need `ContainerReference1`, `ContainerReference2` sorting?

Comment: the Union operator does not preserve the order of the elements.

Comment: Error `sortingExpressions.Add(containers1Sorting);` can't convert `System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable` to `System.Func...`

Comment: Error `mergedSorting(mergedContainers)` can't convert `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` to `System.Linq.IQueryable`

Comment: expressions.SelectMany(x => x).AsQueryable();

Comment: How can I insert that into sorting expression for containers3? `.OrderBy(y => y.Email).ThenBy(y => y.DisplayName)`

Comment: var containers3Sorting = new Func<IQueryable<Container>, IOrderedQueryable<Container>>(q => q
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateUpdated)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Emails.OrderBy(y => y.Email).ThenBy(y => y.DisplayName)));

Comment: Can we replace `.SelectMany` with something else because I see it returns Enumerable and it will execute SQL query and upload to memory? And one more error after that code I do `var total = containers.Count()` and it throws error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: replaced `.SelectMany` with `expressions.Aggregate((acc, i) => acc.Union(i));` and no more errors. Updated answer with working code. Thanks!

Comment: can you please help with error ```Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[ContactEmail]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[ContactEmail]```?